# How to collect an iterator into a Result?

Tags: rust

I currently have the following function:

```
fn filter_files<P>(input_path: P) -> Result<Vec<DirEntry>, Box<dyn error::Error>> where P: AsRef<Path> {
    fs::read_dir(input_path)?
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|res| res.ok())
        .filter(|dir_entry| dir_entry.file_name().to_str().unwrap().starts_with("_x"))
        .collect()
}
```

Where I am attempting to filter out files that start with `_x`. I would like to have this function return the filtered `Vec<DirEntry>` directly instead of having to make a variable. My issue is that I can not get the function signature correct. I am getting an error with

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Result<Vec<DirEntry>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `DirEntry`
    --> src/main.rs:18:10
     |
18   |         .collect()
     |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `Result<Vec<DirEntry>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=DirEntry>`
```

I am wondering what the correct signature for this function's return type should be given that the `fs::read_dir(...)` could return an `io::Error` I know that I need to be returning a `Result` type. Is the usage of `collect()` correct or is this an incorrect usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is a little misleading here, you can collect into a `Result` but only when the iterators [items are of type `Result<A, E>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E-for-Result%3CV%2C%20E%3E).

Since you know all your items exist and did not result in an error (your items are of type `DirEntry` not `Result<DirEntry, _>`) what you want to do instead is to wrap your known good result in a variant of `Result` such as `Ok`:

```rust
fn filter_files<P>(input_path: P) -> std::io::Result<Vec<DirEntry>> where P: AsRef<Path> {
    Ok(fs::read_dir(input_path)?
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|res| res.ok())
        .filter(|dir_entry| dir_entry.file_name().to_str().unwrap().starts_with("_x"))
        .collect())
}
```